# Horizontally Align Tworesponsive Images

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

Still learning responsive web design and ran into a snag.

Is there a way I can make these two linked images horizontally aligned instead of being on top of each other while still maintaining responsiveness?
Basically I need these images to be horizontally on the same line while still being responsive.

Would it be best to have two div tags for each image? Or two images in a single div? Im not sure.

You can see what I'm doing with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odw3vru8/).

```
#header {
padding-top: 1%;
padding-bottom: .5%;
background-color: white;
}
#header img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 20%;
width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/odw3vru8/8/

Add:

```
#header {
    /* If you want to center align the images horizontally */
    text-align:center
}

#header img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```